# Custom authentication middleware for specific routes in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-middleware

I implemented a custom authentication setup for my Django project. There are some user roles for users. Now I want to ensure that some specific routs may acceptable only of specific user roles. Let's say the `edit/uploaded-files` can be acceptable only for the user with `role = 1`. So I created a middleware for that.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class HRMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if not (user and user.is_authenticated() and user.email):
            return redirect('')
        if user.role_id.id != 1:
            raise 403
        return None
```

Now how can i apply this middleware for some specific routes only ?
I found some solutions like using decorator `@decorator_from_middleware(MyMiddleware)`
and specifying the routes in middle ware. Is there any better way to do this ? Actually I am a Laravel developer. This is my first Django project. In laravel we can specify the middlewares in the routes. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
URLS = ['/some_path/']

class HRMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        user = request.user
        if not (user and user.is_authenticated() and user.email) and request.path in URLS:
            return redirect('')
        if user.role_id.id != 1:
            raise 403
        return None
```

Comment: I tried this solution already. But the problem is, each time i define a route for HR then I want to specify it in middleware also. Is there any another options ?

Comment: Try to use regular expressions, than you can make complete url-routes and subroutes in the rule with a single entry

Answer (score 0):

This is better I think

```
from django.http import Http404
    URLS = ['/dashboard/']
    
    class HRMiddleware:
        def __init__(self, get_response):
            self.get_response = get_response
        def __call__(self, request):
            user = request.user
            response = self.get_response(request)
            if not (user and user.is_authenticated and user.email) and request.path in URLS:
 return redirect('')
    if user.role_id.id != 1:
                raise Http404
            return response
```